# Dynamic HTML content - "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using MVC 3 and Razor.

I have a page where you can create a Vendor. On the front-end, a vendor's page has 3 things: A name, a description (HTML), and multiple tabs that contain HTML. My client wants the tabs to be dynamic, they want to be able to add/edit/delete tabs and content when they add a vendor.

So here's my database design:

```
Vendors
-------------------
VendorID (PK)
Name
Description

VendorTabs
-------------------
VendorTabID (PK)
VendorID (FK)
Title
Content
```

Here's my view model:

```
public class VendorViewModel
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int VendorId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller post method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(VendorViewModel viewModel, string[] tabTitles, string[] tabContent)
{
    var vendor = new Vendor();
    vendor.Name = viewModel.Name;
    vendor.Description = viewModel.Description;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tabTitles.Length; i++)
        {
            vendor.VendorTabs.Add(new VendorTab
            {
                VendorID = vendor.VendorID,
                Title = tabTitles[i],
                Content = tabContent[0]
            });
        }

        _vendorsRepository.SaveVendor(vendor);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(viewModel);     // validation error, so redisplay same view
}
```

In my view, I have functionality to dynamically add/remove fields for a tab title and a tab description. They are passed to the controller through the arrays `tabTitles` and `tabContent`. But when I post the form with HTML in the dynamic tab content, I get the following error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

I ran into this problem before, with the Description field for my Vendor. After some research, I saw that I can add the `AllowHtml` annotation.

How can I apply the same functionality to my dynamic content?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

instead of arrays `tabTitle` and `tabContent`, structure your viewmodel in a way that you can put the `AllowHtmlAttribute` on each individual property that could take in user content, and then just include a List of these in the Model you are binding the View to

```
public class TabViewModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I have `IEnumerable<TabViewModel> Tabs` as a property of `VendorViewModel` now. If I'm not using the arrays `tabTitle` and `tabContent`, how can I associate my dynamic content with `Tabs`?

Comment: ha. I added an answer and realized it basically was the exact same as yours (I dont like reading others before mine to ensure mine is original) +1 : )

Comment: Create a property in your TabViewModel specifically for these lists as qntmfred said so you aren't relying on dynamic binding, otherwise I think you need ValidateRequest(false) which is not recommended in general.

Comment: The fields should be named like Tabs[0].Title etc. The Tabs property should probably be of type TabViewModel[].

Answer (score 0):

How about make [AllowHtml] string[] TabContent {get;set;} a property of the Model?