# mvc3 field contains html text with validation

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have text field that may contain html text (like

```
<b>Dickens</b>
```

) in razor view,
I display this field with

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.CurrentAuthor.AboutAuthorE)
```

when click in any submit buttons, mvc3 throw exception

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (CurrentAuthor.AboutAuthorE="<div align=justify><...").
```

how can I solve this error?

Comment: can it be something like this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774161/ie-only-a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-clien

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218807/dynamic-html-content-a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected

Comment: Thanks A.B.Cade your links was very helpfull, I found the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to store basic formatting consider bbcode

www.bbcode.org

A good editor is Markdown 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown

If you do require more than the basic formatting that something like Markdown can give you consider adding the AllowHtml  attribute to your model

```
[AllowHtml] 
public string AboutAuthorE { get; set; }
```

for details see [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)